# IPhone Safari 302 Redirects open new windows

Tags: iphone, asp.net, redirect

I have a fairly standard ASP.Net web application which is used via mobile safari on the iPhone.

Some users who have a link to the web application placed on their desktop via profile are reporting that when navigating between pages (which I do on the server with Response.Redirect after specific events or via standard anchor tags in other cases (no target specified)) that Safari opens a new window instead of reusing the existing window.

Because of this, any login token/cookie etc (i'm using the built-in ASP.Net membership stuff), is now gone for that new browser window and the login prompt is shown.

The problem doesn't happen every time, and I can't seem to replicate it on my device (but i'm not deploying the shortcut via profile)

As you can probably imagine, it's quite frustrating for the users to have to log in every time, and you can't fix an issue you can't replicate.

My question is, has anyone heard of this issue and/or know a workaround?
The app is NOT iPhone specific, that is, it is used in a full desktop browser as well, and the logins stay like you'd expect there - and the same window is reused repeatedly.

I've considered a few possibilities, but have been drawing a blank as far as what might be causing this or how I can resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any iPhone meta tags set (to remove the url bar or the toolbar, for instance?) If you do, the phone will assume it's a native web app, and urls will open in a new safari window, like they would for any other native app.

Comment: Just the following:
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="aa-iphone-logo.png" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=352;" /> 

Do you think that the viewport meta is causing it to treat it as a native app and as such, any links (not 302 redirects but actual anchor clicks) become new windows?

Comment: One of the sections is actually iPhone optimised and it uses a few more metas - 
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />

but the issue is occuring on other pages as well.. as far as has been reported. 
When I open the app from a safari window on my phone (not from a desktop shortcut) I can't replicate the issue - it stays in the same window always

Comment: This issue looks similar: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2008/10/9/Two-iPhone-development-tips-and-jQuery-to-the-rescue however he's solved it by Ajax loading the contents of the href into a div on the page - if i'm returning full pages (which a typical anchor would return) then we'll end up with nested HTML/HEAD/BODY etc tags inside content divs on subsequent navigations. 
Converting the whole app to be ajax page loads isn't really an option, either.

Comment: The web-app capable might be your culprit, but yes, AJAX loading the content onto the page is the way web apps are designed to work. Could you put a simple piece of javascript code on the page that causes <a> links to request using an XHR, instead of a typical request? It would be a bit of work, but if you can serve this file to mobile clients, it would do the job

Comment: This was the issue, the shortcut on the home screen was set to "Full Screen" which causes the application to open any <a href=""> in new windows

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking advantage of using the web app in full screen mode (where it is bookmarked to the launch screen next to native apps) you can prevent it from jumping out of fullscreen mode by and in to safari replacing  type links with javascript.

```
location.href = '/yourPath';
```

This is a nifty trick which even works if you are linking to an outside URL, like doing an OAuth to Facebook and back.

I have a blog post on this here: http://www.aaroncoleman.net/post/2011/07/29/Keeping-iPhone-Web-App-in-Fullscreen-mode-from-Homescreen-Launcher.aspx